# Cannot import simple files in a NodeJS app

Tags: node.js

When I run this app, I get this error

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\New folder\App' imported from C:\New folder\index.js
Did you mean to import ../App.js?
```

App.js

```
export class App {}
```

index.js

```
import { App } from "./App";
const app = new App();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20"
  },
  "exports": null,
  "type": "module"
}
```

command

```
node index.js
```

If I change it to  `import { App } from "./App.js";` (add the .js) it works. But the reality is, I have a much more complicated project using Typescript and when it compiles it also does not use import statements with `.js`. What's going on here? Since when do we need to include the file extension?